# Raphael resizing not working correctly

Tags: jquery, drawing, height, raphael

I'm having fun trying to make a little tool to test screen sizes. So far the Blue width resizes correctly, but the Height and textbox do not. Does anybody notice anything wrong with this code?

The tool upon page load renders correctly.

[image]

```
/* Sizing Script */
$(document).ready(function() {                
    var canvas = $('#canvas');
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();                
    var txt = ('height: ' + h + '\n\n' + 'width: ' + w);
    draw(canvas.attr('id'), canvas.height(), canvas.width(), txt);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var h = $(window).height();
        var w = $(window).width();                   
        draw(canvas.attr('id'), canvas.height(), canvas.width(),txt);



    });
});
function draw( id, h, w, txt) {

    var paper = Raphael(id, '100%', '100%'); //create new paper instance based on holder height and width

    paper.setViewBox(0, 0, 1500, 1500, true);
    paper.clear();
    var height_h = paper.rect(10, 0, 100, 10).attr({
        fill: '#291919',
        stroke: '#291919'
    });               
    var height_l = paper.rect(10, h-10, 100, 10).attr({
        fill: '#291919',
        stroke: '#291919'
    });
    var height_v = paper.rect(55, 0, 10, h).attr({
        fill: '#291919',
        stroke: '#291919'
    });

    var width_l = paper.rect(0, 10, 10, 100).attr({
        fill: '#549EFF',
        stroke: '#549EFF'
    });
    var width_r = paper.rect(w-10, 10, 10, 100).attr({
        fill: '#549EFF',
        stroke: '#549EFF'
    });
    var width_h = paper.rect(0, 55, w-10, 10).attr({
        fill: '#549EFF',
        stroke: '#549EFF'
    });

    var textbox = paper.rect(h/2 - 50, w/2 - 100, 200, 100).attr({
        fill: '#E6E6E6',
        stroke: '#ddd',
        'stroke-width': 5
    });
    var height_b = paper.rect(h / 2 - 12, w / 2 - 80, 125, 25).attr({
        fill: '#291919',
        stroke: '#ddd',
        'stroke-width': 5,
        opacity: 0.6
    });
    var width_b = paper.rect(h / 2 - 12, w / 2 - 45, 125, 25).attr({
        fill: '#549EFF',
        stroke: '#ddd',
        'stroke-width': 5,
        opacity: 0.6
    });
    var t = paper.text(h / 2 + 50, w / 2 - 50, txt).attr({
        "font-size": 16,
        "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"                    
    });

}
```

HTML

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

CSS

```
body{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
#canvas{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;                
     text-align: center;
     border: solid 1px black;
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I created a jsfiddle, but it doesn't render correctly at all. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbBFk/) I'm guessing that if I can fix the height issue both the black bar and box will render correctly. Is there a way to clear everything and just force re-render on resize?

Comment: The first thing you need to sort out is the params to paper.rect, you are supplying height and width it seems, it want width then height. http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.rect

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, for those of you who would like to look at it.

Javascript

```
/* Sizing Script */
$(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = $('#canvas');
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();
    var txt = ('height: ' + h + ' px\n\n' + 'width: ' + w + ' px');
    draw(canvas.attr('id'), canvas.height(), canvas.width(), txt);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var canvas = $('#canvas');
        canvas.empty();
        var h = $(window).height();
        var w = $(window).width();
        var txt = ('height: ' + h + ' px\n\n' + 'width: ' + w + ' px');
        draw(canvas.attr('id'), canvas.height(), canvas.width(), txt);
    });
});
function draw( id, h, w, txt) {

    var paper = Raphael(id, '100%', '100%'); //create new paper instance based on holder height and width
    var vert_width = w * .01;
    var vert_height = h * .01;
    var height_h = paper.rect(vert_width, 0, 100, vert_width).attr({
        fill: '#46FA70',
        stroke: '#46FA70'
    });
    var height_l = paper.rect(vert_width, h - vert_width, 100, vert_width).attr({
        fill: '#46FA70',
        stroke: '#46FA70'
    });
    var height_v = paper.rect(55, 0, vert_width, h).attr({
        fill: '#46FA70',
        stroke: '#46FA70'
    });

    var width_l = paper.rect(0, vert_height, vert_height, 100).attr({
        fill: '#549EFF',
        stroke: '#549EFF'
    });
    var width_r = paper.rect(w - vert_height, vert_height, vert_height, 100).attr({
        fill: '#549EFF',
        stroke: '#549EFF'
    });
    var width_h = paper.rect(0, 55, w - vert_height, vert_height).attr({
        fill: '#549EFF',
        stroke: '#549EFF'
    });

    var txtbox = [80, 75];
    var textbox = paper.rect(txtbox[0] , txtbox[1] , 200, 100).attr({
        fill: '#E6E6E6',
        stroke: '#ddd',
        'stroke-width': 5
    });
    var height_b = paper.rect(txtbox[0]+37, txtbox[1]+19, 125, 25).attr({
        fill: '#46FA70',
        stroke: '#ddd',
        'stroke-width': 5,
        opacity: 0.6
    });
    var width_b = paper.rect(txtbox[0]+ 37, txtbox[1] + 55, 125, 25).attr({
        fill: '#549EFF',
        stroke: '#ddd',
        'stroke-width': 5,
        opacity: 0.6
    });
    var t = paper.text(txtbox[0] + 100, txtbox[1] + 50, txt).attr({
        "font-size": 16,
        "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"                    
    });

}
```

and CSS

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:#000000;
}
#canvas{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;                
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you have answered your own question, I was looking at this on the way home this evening and thought I would share with you what I came up with.

There is no overhead of recreating a paper on resize, I just reposition the existing elements and resized the paper.

You or others may find it useful. I updated your [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kbBFk/2/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var canvas = $('#canvas'), paper, 
        top, vCentre, bottom, left, hCentre, right;
        var w = $(window).innerWidth();
        var h = $(window).innerHeight();
        draw(canvas.attr('id'), w, h);

        // on resize call the update with new dimensions
        $(window).resize(function() {
            w = $(window).innerWidth();
            h = $(window).innerHeight();
            update(w,h);
        });
    });

    // draw function takes id, width and height
    function draw( id, w, h) {
        paper = Raphael(id, '100%', '100%'); 

        // create our rectangular sections
        top = getRect(0, 0, 100, 10, '#46FA70');
        vCentre = getRect(45, 0, 10, h, '#46FA70');
        bottom = getRect(0, h-10, 100, 10, '#46FA70');
        left = getRect(0, 0, 10, 100, '#549EFF');
        hCentre = getRect(0, 45, w, 10, '#549EFF');
        right = getRect(w-25, 0, 10, 100, '#549EFF');
    }

    // helper to create rectangles
    function getRect(x, y, w, h, color){
        return paper.rect(x, y, w, h).attr({
            fill: color,
            stroke: color
        });
    }

    // update the paper and reposition the rect elements
    function update(w, h){
        paper.setSize(w, h);

        // reisize vertical centre and move bottom
        vCentre.attr({height: h-10});
        bottom.attr({x:0, y:h-10});

        // resize horizontal centre and move right
        hCentre.attr({width: w-10});
        right.attr({x:w-10, y:0});
    }
```